# Change Spacing Between Internal TOC numbering and subsection titles

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, titletoc

In my Supporting Info `chapter`, I have my `subsections` defined as

`\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thechapter-\Roman{section}.\arabic{subsection}}`

Which is the format requested of me by my professor.

This makes my subsection numbering quite wide, once I'm at the 3rd section (because of the roman numerals).  This is only a problem in my internal 2nd `toc` which I generate with the `titletoc` package.  Following the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13692/16782) using:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@subsection}{\@dottedtocline{2}{4.0em}{3.9em}}
\makeatother
```

I followed the same route to change the spacing betweeen the `section number` and the `title` in my `toc`, but found that it changes both the spacing between the `section number` and `subsection title` for both my main `toc` and my internal one.

I only want it to change the spacing for the 2nd, smaller `toc` within my chapter.

I using other tricks shown to me earlier such as adding the command to the `toc` with `protect` and `addtocontents` but was not successful.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt plus2pt}
\def\baselinestretch{1.6}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setpnumwidth{2.5em}
\setrmarg{3.5em}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@subsection}{\@dottedtocline{2}{4.0em}{3.9em}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\protect\OnehalfSpacing}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection} 
\mainmatter
\DoubleSpacing   
\chapter{Chap1}
\section{Chap1Sec1}
\section{Chap1Sec2}
\chapter{Chap2}
\section{Chap2Sec1}
\section{Chap2Sec2}
\subsection{Chap2Sec2Subsec1}
\SingleSpacing
\chapter{Chap3}
\settocdepth{section}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter-\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thechapter-\Roman{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{S-\arabic{page}}
\section{Chap3Sec1}
\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec2}
\bigskip
\startcontents
\printcontents{}{2}{\addtocontents{ptc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec1}\clearpage
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec2}\clearpage
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec3}\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec4}
\stopcontents
\section{Chap3Sec3}\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec4}\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec5}\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec6}\clearpage
\renewcommand{\thepage}{A-\arabic{page}}
\setcounter{page}{9}
\chapter{Chap4}
\settocdepth{subsection}
\section{Chap4Sec1}\clearpage
\section{Chap4Sec2}\clearpage
\subsection{Chap4Sec2Subsec1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've inserted the redefinition of `\l@subsection` exactly where it's needed and inside a group. This makes the redefinition local, reverting back to what it was before after the group is closed:

```
%...
\section{Chap3Sec2}
\bigskip
\startcontents
\printcontents{}{2}{\addtocontents{ptc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}}
\lipsum[1-2]

\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\begingroup%
  \protect\makeatletter
  \protect\def\protect\l@subsection{\protect\@dottedtocline{2}{4.0em}{3.9em}}
  \protect\makeatother
}
\makeatother

\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec1}\clearpage
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec2}\clearpage
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec3}\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec4}
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\endgroup%
}
%...
```

You still have the original subsection spacing in the main ToC:

[image]

Yet your mini-ToC in the Supporting Chapter has a much wider spacing:

[image]

Here's the original, now updated, MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt plus2pt}
\def\baselinestretch{1.6}\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\setpnumwidth{2.5em}
\setrmarg{3.5em}
\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\protect\OnehalfSpacing}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection} 
\mainmatter
\DoubleSpacing   
\chapter{Chap1}
\section{Chap1Sec1}
\section{Chap1Sec2}
\chapter{Chap2}
\section{Chap2Sec1}
\section{Chap2Sec2}
\subsection{Chap2Sec2Subsec1}
\SingleSpacing
\chapter{Chap3}
\settocdepth{section}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter-\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thechapter-\Roman{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{S-\arabic{page}}
\section{Chap3Sec1}
\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec2}
\bigskip
\startcontents
\printcontents{}{2}{\addtocontents{ptc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}}
\lipsum[1-2]

\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\begingroup%
  \protect\makeatletter
  \protect\def\protect\l@subsection{\protect\@dottedtocline{2}{4.0em}{3.9em}}
  \protect\makeatother
}
\makeatother

\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec1}\clearpage
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec2}\clearpage
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec3}\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec4}
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\endgroup%
}
\stopcontents
\section{Chap3Sec3}\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec4}\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec5}\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec6}\clearpage
\renewcommand{\thepage}{A-\arabic{page}}
\setcounter{page}{9}
\chapter{Chap4}
\settocdepth{subsection}
\section{Chap4Sec1}\clearpage
\section{Chap4Sec2}\clearpage
\subsection{Chap4Sec2Subsec1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks for such a quick response!